# Is there a better way to find rows with all column with values?

Tags: c#, vb.net, sql-server-2005, .net-3.5

I need to find rows in resultsets that have every column without null.

These result sets got variable number of columns.

Currently, the only way that I can think of is creating a view on each result set and filter this way:

```
 select field1, field2, field3, field4, ...
 from "huge query"
 where field1 is not null and  
       field2 is not null and  
       field3 is not null and  
       field4 is not null and
       ...  is not null
```

is there a better way to do this in a stored procedure/function in SQL Server or in .net code (c# or vb.net) ?

And what about doing something like

```
 select field1, field2, field3, field4, ...
 from "huge query"
 (return to .net apps or insert into #temptable)
```

and then in a stored procedure/function or .net code(c# / vb.net) loop through all rows / columns and flag or remove every row that got any null?

I'm talking about easily over 50 different kind of resultsets and it might grow over time, so I'm looking for a generic / easily maintainable way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since nulls propagate, if they're all the same datatype, try

```
where colA + ColB + ColC, etc Is Not Null
```

If they're not, then convert them all (the ones that are not already a string) to char first, and then concatenate them.

```
where Str(ColA) + Str(ColB) + Str(ColC), etc Is Not Null
```

Comment: +1 too, did not knew '+' could work with other type than string

Comment: I updated my question, I might use your solution in the end, if there is no better way

Comment: Checked this one but I will still use my solution of "field is not null and ...", since finding the datatype of each field to make sure they are not a varchar/char is going to be really long, at least "is not null" on each field will work no matter what are the datatype

Comment: If you have many fields and they are not not all the same type, then your solutio nis probably best...

Answer (score 3):

Your method is not pretty but I actually think it will perform the best. Another way is to do

```
WHERE (field1 + field2 + field3 + field4) IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

If field1, field2, field2... fieldX are string, you may want to try :

```
select field1, field2, field3, field4, ...
from "huge query"
where field1 + field2 + field3 + ... + fieldX is not null
```